# Cloudinary image breaking in mobile resolution

Tags: html, reactjs, image, responsive, cloudinary

Using cloudinary react SDK

```
         <CloudinaryImageTag
              crop="thumb"
              gravity="face"
              quality="100"
              height={small ? 80 : 168}
              width={small ? 80 : 128}
              src={get(profile, 'image.medium')}
              alt={get(profile, 'name', 'artist photo')}
         />
```

**Works perfectly in large screen**
[image]

**Breaks when I try to load the same on a small screen**
[image]

I am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: What are the Cloudinary URLs that are generated in the large view? Feel free to exclude your cloud name for privacy.

Comment: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/c_thumb,f_auto,g_face,h_220,q_100,r_8,w_220/https://quality-static.truelinked.net/profileMedia/34be1cac-dffc-4876-a1cb-fbb03840504e/9e18bba9-4d94-4635-bb83-5e1b1b5d8ed4-medium.png

Changed my cloud to demo

Comment: What about the response headers? Maybe add some of those details to the post.